# ...and started (walking) down the corridor

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, sentence-meaning, verbs

The man stepped off the elevator and **started** down the corridor.

I have seen *started* used like this before without adding eg. *walking* after it. Is it perfectly natural use of *started*?

Answer (score 1):

It **is** a perfectly natural use of *'started'*.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/start)'s definition 1.3 of **start** is:

> verb
> *[no object, with adverbial of direction]* Begin to move or travel.

Their examples include, *he started for the door* and *we started out into the snow*.

According to [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=start), **start** evolved from the Old English *styrtan* and its variants, which meant *to leap up or to move or spring suddenly.* By 1300 this meaning had evolved into *flinch or recoil in alarm*, which is still one of its meanings today.

The meaning *begin to move or travel* only appeared in 1821. It bears no suggestion of alarm or suddenness.

Answer (score 0):

The word has a rich etymological history. [Originally](https://www.etymonline.com/word/start#etymonline_v_22010), it meant "move briskly, move swiftly, spring suddenly, recoil in alarm" and I think it still preserves this meaning. I don't come across it very often but [this ngram chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=start_INF%20down&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t3%3B%2Cstart_INF%20down%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bstarted%20down%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bstart%20down%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bstarting%20down%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bstarts%20down%3B%2Cc0) says it's quite common.

I don't think it's simply interchangeable with "walking" because there must be an element of suddenness, rush, alertness. He didn't just nonchalantly walked down the passage, he rather hurried/flew/ran through the corridor.